# TFS Get Latest Not Grabbing References

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, version-control

I've been having issues recently with pulling down a new copy of a repository from my TFS server.  Each time I do this most(if not all) of the references are broken.

They either have to be deleted and re-added, or removed and re-installed using NuGet.

Is there a simple way to do something like a Git-Clone (Most likley Get-Latest-Recursive) so that I can pull down a repo, build it, and being working?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't store NuGet packages in source control. In this scenario, chances are they are source controlled incorrectly (wrong path, partially source controlled). If you have a *packages* folder, delete it and create a *.tfignore* file (for TFVC) or a *.gitignore* file (for Git) and allow the packages to be restored automatically on build.

Comment: So for example:

If I was using the iTextSharp NuGet package I would be adding a reference under "References" in visual studio.  If I'm using external DLL's those would also be under references.  

Adding a .tfignore file including the external dlls as well as NuGet packages, so that source control doesn't see them.

On a Rebuild will the packages be rebuilt and use-able in this instance now?  Or will I still have to re-install the latest version?