# How can I deal with DLL references in TFS?

Tags: c#, tfs

I create my first TFS (2013 Express) project and added my solution (MVC5) to that project.

I then checked everything in and deleted it and restored from TFS to ensure that I have a working copy.

It was at this point I realized that I have a "DLL Reference" folder that sits outside of my solution.

What is the proper way for storing 3rd party dll referenced like this in TFS so that I can ensure I have a working solution?

EDIT:
This is not dll's from Nuget.  These are 3rd party dll's that I am referencing from a folder.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TFS Get Latest Not Grabbing References](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39661958/tfs-get-latest-not-grabbing-references)

Comment: That link references Nuget files.  This is 3rd party dll's that I am not getting from Nuget.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easy-though-not-so-clean way is to create a dummy project, with no source files and a single folder (you could use the assemblies folder you already have) containing your dependencies. You can then add the dummy project to your solution and it will be synchronized by TFS.

There is an alternative solution, without including a dummy project.

From within Visual Studio, you can use Source Control Explorer to add files to TFS even if they are not in a project of your solution.

You can also do this from Windows Explorer. As long as you are in a folder that is part of a configured Workspace, you should be able see a "Team Foundation Server" drop-down menu when you right-click the folder.

The downside to this is that when someone needs to download your solution files to a new machine, they will have to manually download that folder too (via Source Control Explorer or Windows Explorer).

Comment: I added the folder as suggested via Source Control Explorer.  That did the trick.  I also didn't consider Nuget dll's so I will need to revisit that in the link that was previously added.  Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

Create a folder in TFS at solution level, call it dependencies, binaries or give any name you prefer. Add 3rd party files to this folder. Remove and add references to your project from this folder.

Answer (score 0):

I know I'm a bit late to the party, but for anyone having a similar problem, you can create a folder in your project called "`ExternalDLLs`" and add the DLLs you need in there. Add references to these DLLs in your Project. Then include this folder in your Source Control and Push it up.

By default, Source Controls, ignore files with certain extensions (e.g. `dll`). Ensure that you add this folder to the Source Control, you can usually do it from your IDE or there may be a `.gitignore` file (or similar)

If you are trying to Push the `bin` folder with the DLLs up to your Source Control, the bin folder contents become Read-Only. That is why, this separate folder needs to be created.

Answer (score 0):

I always recommend against committing binaries to source control. One way you can maintain these dependencies is to create your own nuget package, and host it internally on your own nuget server.